# Update an existing column value

Tags: cassandra

What happens when a new value for an existing column is added? Will the older value be overwritten by the new value? Or the older value will also retain and can be retrieved (similar to simpleDB)?

Answer (score 6):

The older value is overwritten (technically, hidden by the new and eventually garbage collected).