# How to update a cassandra column?

Tags: cassandra, thrift

I am an absolute newbie at cassandra, and I request for some help.

```
client.insert(ByteBuffer.wrap(userIDKey), cp, new Column(ByteBuffer.wrap("name".getBytes(UTF8)), ByteBuffer
                .wrap("George Clinton".getBytes(UTF8)), new Date().getTime()), CL);
```

Now, I would like to update the name, and add a suffix to the name, 'Jr.'. A very simple use case, but I am unable to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Insert the new values for the same row key and column name(s), and they should over-write the old values.

See:

[Update an existing column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847426/update-an-existing-column-value)

and:

[Cassandra update column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699052/cassandra-update-column)

Comment: Also make sure the time stamp for the new row is larger then the one for the first row.

Answer (score 3):

DNA's answer is correct, but it also looks like you're using raw Thrift instead of one of the [high level Java clients](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ClientOptions) that are available. You can avoid a lot of work and pitfalls by using one of these instead.